# How to prevent selection of certain rows in an HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am currently trying to setup a table in HTML with 2 columns of information. The 3rd column has a button, and when pressed, it deletes that entry from the table.

What I am looking for is that the user cannot select an item below the first entry in the table. The code I have for the table right now is listed below.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Issue</th> 
    <th>Select</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>

    </td>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per i understand your question you need to delete first row not a second row.

Please see below code if you want to do like this.

```js
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  if(row.rowIndex<=1)
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Issue</th> 
    <th>Select</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>

    </td>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this code

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="tbUser">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Amit</td>
    <td>Ghatkopar</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vicky</td>
    <td>Powai</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sunny</td>
    <td>Powai</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>NewYork</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#tbUser").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```